# Partial differentiation of implicit function

Tags: partial-derivative

How do calculate Partial differentiation of implicit function $$f( x+y+z,x^2+y^2+z^2)=0$$

Comment: Use the multi-variable chain rule.

Comment: Answer for this question is.    (y-z)dz/dx +(x-z)dz/dy=x-y  please explain how i get tji solution

Answer (score 1):

$$f( x+y+z,x^2+y^2+z^2)=0\equiv f(u,v)=0$$where $~u=x+y+z~$ and $~v=x^2+y^2+z^2$.

Now by chain rule $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
$$\implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+2x\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
$$\implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+2y\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}$$
$$\implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}+2z\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$$